# react-native didn't find any iOS simulator in terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, simulator

I'm facing this issue. terminal didn't find any iOS simulator for react native:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow.

Are you using xCode 10? If yes, then check this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19573)

If this doesn't help. Then try running `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone X"` with the version of the device that you need

Also if you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.